# Loading/analyzing a bunch of text files in Pandas/SQL

Tags: sql, pandas, text

I have a few thousand files of text and would like to analyze them for trends/word patterns, etc. I am familiar with both Pandas and SQL but am not sure how to "load" all these files into a table/system such that I can run code on them. Any advice?

Comment: Where are those files now? What format are those files? csv?

Comment: They are a bunch of .txt files

Comment: You can use `pd.read_csv('C:\location\name.txt')` to read one text file

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the same columns in all the text files you can use something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:/location_rawdata_files'#use the path where you stored all txt's
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
lst = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None)
    lst .append(df)
df= pd.concat(lst, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```